# Installing an air gap in a concrete countertop

Tags: plumbing, kitchens, dishwasher

I am remodeling my kitchen; pretty much all of the work except for installing a granite countertop. I am putting in a dishwasher (kitchen previously did not have one) and I would prefer to install an air gap whether or not the local codes require it. However, of the models I looked at on-line, only one discussed mounting support, and it couldn't be mounted on material thicker than 1.25". The countertop people will drill any holes I need for the faucet, etc., I just need to know how to actually fasten one of these things to a 2" thick surface. Any advice on brands that might be made especially for this, or any tricks for extending the fastenings that come with air gaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install faucets or air gaps in thick countertops, simply bore a wide hole (2 1/2 - 3 inches) from the bottom of the countertop halfway through or so.  In your case, they'd have to bore a wide hole at least 3/4 inches up from the bottom.  The hole just needs to be wide enough to provide room to secure the nut.

In concrete countertops, the forms are made with holes pre-cast wide at the bottom and narrow at the top.

Comment: What tool would be best used to accomplish this on a plywood underlayment? Some kind of rotary tool? What if there is already a hole there and you just need to recess it a little bit on the bottom? (Hypothetical question) why don't they just make air gaps with an extra inch of threads?

Comment: My question seems to have an answer elsewhere: https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/48957/74858